# Remember file names -> perform action to files -> save files again with remembered name

Tags: macos, finder, automator

I want to send the files to the "Perform OCR" action and save them with their original file name. Is that possible? (maybe rather with an apple script?)

it's basically [this](http://www.documentsnap.com/acrobat-applescript-for-scansnap-ocr/) for [Prizmo](http://www.creaceed.com/prizmo).

[image]

Comment: What is the "Perform OCR" actions inputs and outputs when you run it? What happens when you select multiple images, how does the *Output File Format* behave?

Comment: FWIW, *Set Variable Value* and *Get Variable Value* might work. Alternatively, *Perform OCR* might not even rename the file if you don't specify a name. It really depends on what *Perform OCR* actually does in detail.

Comment: If you can figure out the name of the OCR process, this is easy to do on the command line.

Comment: Judging from what I read in [the manual](http://www.creaceed.com/assets/prizmo/userguideprizmo2.pdf), it looks like multiple images get collapsed to a single file, so this sucks. Unfortunately, without spending 80€ I cannot try it myself. You might be able to reuse a single file's name using Automator variables as mentioned above.

Comment: @DanielBeck Thank you for your reply. Input: Image/PDF files -> Output: "one" PDF (Image + Searchable Text) ... Does that help? How do I receive just the file name with "Set / Get Value of Variable" ?

Comment: That's how far I got without a serial number. Have you tried to see how the action behaves with 1 / multiple files when entering one destination file name, just to see what happens?

Comment: Very unfortunate ...  » http://cdn.dropmark.com/22603/2829165d476e78afdf83596d70f27a87330a8f05/Screen%20Shot%202013-01-14%20at%207.34.34%20PM.png